# Incomplete log after svn -> mercurial conversion

Tags: svn, mercurial

I ran `hg convert -A AUTHORS_FILE repo` on a subversion repository. If I run `hg log` in the newly created mercurial repository I only get the last 8 changes in the subversion's revision history.

Is there a way to convert my subversion repository and maintain the entire log? I know this isn't a lot of information, I'm not sure what would be helpful debugging info in this case. Ask me and I will try to find the info.

EDIT:
The subversion repository in question contains multiple projects (this does not translate well to mercurial), but I only wanted one project. The solution was something along the lines of:

```
hg --config convert.svn.trunk=project/trunk --config convert.svn.branches=project/branches --config convert.svn.tags=project/tags convert file:///net/vol1/svn
```

convert.svn.* indicates where the trunk, branches, and tags of the project are to the convert tool. /net/vol1/svn is where the svn repository is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think and expect, that you have fundamental layout change in revision, before each you can't get history converted - **if** you converted from repo-root **and|or** doesn't define tree-relatedsvn.* options in .hgrc

How you can debug your case

- Check with svn-client log of your repository (`svn URL-OF-REPO-ROOT -v` will show you files, affected by revision with full path) - if layout was changed, you have to convert source repo in two or more steps, convert only range with permanent layout at once with correct options

`svn.trunk`

> Relative path to the trunk (default: "trunk")

`svn.branches`

> Relative path to tree of branches (default: "branches")`

`svn.tags`

> Relative path to tree of tags (default: "tags")

(in command line) and `--rev` option

- For the same job (checking layout) you can use `svn ls URL@PEG-REV` or recursively over tree with -R
- you can convert Subversion repository to Mercurial repo transparently, using [HGSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) extension (you clone Subversion repo, can pull|push with it, but cloned local repo is Mercurial repository)

Comment: HGSubversion is not an option for me. It does not install well because of my setup.

Comment: This ended up getting at what I needed to do. The subversion repository in question contains multiple projects, but I only wanted one project. The solution was something along the lines of:

hg --config convert.svn.trunk=project/trunk --config convert.svn.branches=project/branches --config convert.svn.tags=project/tags convert file:///net/vol1/svn

which indicates where the trunk, branches, and tags of the project are to the convert tool.